# for implementing SSO, can we use CAS Protocol with RestApi which is currently used by a mobile application?

Tags: rest, grails, single-sign-on, cas

Please find below the scenario.

We have an internal mobile application only for our company employees. Our mobile app interacts with our REST API (say A on war A1) which in turn uses a security plugin that can authenticate users using LDAP. And another desktop application also uses a different restapi (say B on war A2 but deployed on the same server). This restApi B also uses the same security plugin that can authenticate users via LDAP.

My aim is to achieve SSO for these 2 applications along with couple other applications which can involve both mobile and desktop apps.

I am trying to implement CAS architecture. I have already setup CAS Server and configured with LDAP, authentication is working. Now comes the part of setting up CAS Clients. So my question is, whether we can use CAS Protocol (I would like to go with CAS first before SAMl or Oauth) to configure our security plugin which can be used by all our RestApi projects (in grails)?
(Condition: The RestApi should be configured such that it can support not only desktop application but also mobile applications)

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want, you can use CAS as oauth provider for your mobile clients and utilize the spring security rest plugin -- here's a poc for grails 3 I did recently https://github.com/snimavat/rest-oauth

Comment: Thanks very much Sudhir but my question is whether we can use CAS protocol instead of OAuth to achieve SSO both for mobile and desktop apps? Since I need to support remember me and SLO functionality as well, that's why I want to go with CAS Protocol, since its specs clearly specify that we can do both.

Comment: See this https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html - i would prefer oauth for mobile clients though

Comment: Sudhir, I agree with you that oAuth will be recommended for Mobile clients  and I have read so myself. But I do not understand how does it make any difference whether it is mobile app or web-app since the RestApi will handle the authentication and all the other post/put/get requests.